# How to stop Multiprocess.Pool to move on in the program before it has finished its tasks

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am working with python 3.10 with a large database, on which I need to perform the following operation:

```
OGS_DB[['HOPS', 'GROUP']] = OGS_DB.apply(lambda x: hops_generator(const_id=const_id,    num_hops=n_hops, sat_c=x['SAT'],
                                                            ul_start=x['OGS_Start'], ul_end=x['OGS_End']), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

which will create two new columns of the DF using the method hops_generator.
The hop generator method is doing computations taking as input few parameters of each row of the DF, like SAT, OGS START and OGS END, as well as other configurable parameters. It returns a list of strings (HOPS) and a string (GROUP).
I think the content of this function is not important since it is only doing simple computations based on an external file, so I will not paste the code here.

In order to make it more efficient, I tried to use multiprocess.Pool, in this way:

```
def process_row(args):
row, sat_c, const_id, num_hops, ul_start, ul_end = args
hops, group = hops_generator(sat_c, const_id, num_hops, ul_start, ul_end)
return {'HOPS': hops, 'GROUP': group}
```

And then in the main program:

```
        if __name__ == '__main__':
        with Manager() as manager:
            DB_HOP = manager.list([None] * len(OGS_DB))
            with Pool(processes=cpucores - 3) as pool:
                freeze_support()
                results = pool.map(process_row,
                         [(row, row['SAT'], const_id, n_hops, row['OGS_Start'], row['OGS_End']) for index, row in
                          OGS_DB.iterrows()])
                pool.close()  # No more tasks will be added to the pool
                pool.join()  # Wait for all tasks to complete
            # Extract HOPS and GROUP from results
            hops_list = [result['HOPS'] for result in results]
            group_list = [result['GROUP'] for result in results]
        OGS_DB['HOPS'] = pd.Series(hops_list)
        OGS_DB['GROUP'] = pd.Series(group_list)
```

I used pool.join() to stop the program until this part is completed, but it does not work and so I get errors since the HOP column is not there yet.

```
OGS_DB = OGS_DB.drop('SAT', axis=1)
OGS_DB = OGS_DB.explode('HOPS').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Since the next part of the code requires the 'HOPS' and 'GROUP' columns to be fully created, if the program goes on before their creation I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\FL4NGSO\Development\Flexible_OISL\OISL_flexible.py", line 426, in <module>
    OISL_analysis(Loc)
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\FL4NGSO\Development\Flexible_OISL\OISL_flexible.py", line 99, in OISL_analysis
    OGS_DB = OGS_DB.explode('HOPS').reset_index(drop=True)
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9540, in explode
    result = df[columns[0]].explode()
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3893, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\pizz_lu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3797, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'HOPS'
```

How can I achieve my goal? Thanks.

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. (2) Is the error reproducible or does it happen only sometimes (or in different ways)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I edited the question. The error is simply due to the fact that the program goes on before the pool has finished all the tasks, in this case the creation of the columns. 

And the error is reproducible, it happens everytime even with different scripts, since the problem is still the same: the program goes on when the parallelization results are not yet ready.

Comment: Where is `OGS_DB = OGS_DB.explode('HOPS')` located relative to the main code which contains `OGS_DB['HOPS'] = pd.Series(hops_list)`? The latter line should actually create a column "HOPS" or raise an exception.

Comment: Of course the explode command is located after the line that creates the hops column.
The order is the one showed in the question.

Comment: But how comes that the column is created first and then it is missing? And how should this be related to the multiprocessing pool which was already closed beforehand?

Comment: The issue is that the column SHOULD be created by the pool, and then the program should go on and operate on that column. However, for some reason the program advances to the next lines after the pool before finishing the process that is being parallelized.  It seems like the process row method is not working, the script reaches that point and does nothing, so the column is never created actually.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. According to your code, `pool.map` returns `results`. The pool is closed then and can't influence `results`'s value anymore. Then `hops_list` is extracted from `results`. And then `OGS_DB['HOPS'] = pd.Series(hops_list)` is executed. After that line, if no exception was thrown yet, `OGS_DB` **must** contain a column `HOPS`, regardless of the contents of `hops_list` or `results`.

Comment: Yes, I understand exactly what you mean. After further investigations I understood that the core of the problem is that the `results` are never returned, since the program for some reason doesn't enter the `process_row` method. So now my question is: why is the program not entering in the process row method?

Comment: I don't think so. If the line `results = pool.map(...` was executed, `results` must contain something, maybe an empty list. If the line wouldn't be executed, there would be a NameError (but isn't) when `hops_list = [result['HOPS'] for result in results]` is executed. So `hops_list` **must** contain a list, maybe empty, too short, whatever, but a list. Therefore the line `OGS_DB['HOPS'] = pd.Series(hops_list)` **must** create the column "HOPS". Even `OGS_DB['HOPS'] = pd.Series([])` would do this. The column may consist of `NaN`s only or any garbage but it **must** exist at this point.

Comment: Yes you are indeed correct. However, this gets even weirder because I also tried to modify my process row function to make it as dummy as possible, like to compute and return the square of range(10), but still nothing is returned. In the end I decided to give up the parallelization, and I run the code without it.